# Netgear router becomes unresponsive frequently

Tags: router

I have a Netgear WNR3500v2 router that becomes unresponsive frequently (once a day or so); all connections through the router drop and all pings to the router time out.  New computers timeout when trying to connect wireless; and wired-connected devices don't get assigned IP address.  So far, my only remedy has been to restart the router.

How should I debug the problem?  Is there a known problem with the router?

More details:

- The network consists of two Macs (one running Mountain Lion), iOS devices, two printers, and Boxee
- I couldn't figure out a direct correlation between any event/time with router unresponsiveness, but it become more frequent recently

Comment: How long you've had this router? This could be a sign that its dying, remember its a device thats basically 24 hours on. You can try switching it for another one to see if it keeps happening.

Comment: The router is just over a year old.  It's unlikely that's the router is dying quite yet.

Comment: When you get the problem again connect one of the laptops directly to your modem. If you get normal connectivity then its definitely the router.